# How to Organize Multiple API Calls Into A Single Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, google-analytics

I'm building a web-based analytics app that needs to pull data in from a user's Google Analytics, Mailchimp, and Stripe accounts (there will also be more options in the future.

I know how to connect to 3rd party APIs, but I don't know where to store the code for each API.

I used this to connect: http://readysteadycode.com/howto-access-the-google-analytics-api-with-ruby, but all of the code is stored in a single controller. I know this can't be correct.

Where should I store each API call code and how do I connect to each API with a LINK_TO.

Comment: "Correctness" is subjective. If it works, it works. Doesn't matter much how/where you store code.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, indeed. Controllers should be small.

You could for instance use **interactors**, with [this gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor):

> An interactor is a simple, single-purpose object.

So, one interactor will do one specific thing with an API.

See also how you can use **organizers** with this gem. It's an interactor which has the single purpose to run other interactors, as there will probably be many steps in your app's handling with the APIs you are using.